# "Cannot find module" error when using TypeScript 3 Project References

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I'm trying to get **TypeScript 3's project references** working but struggling to import a function from a referenced project.

I have a **ProjectA** that references **Shared**. Here's the file structure:

```
ProjectA
|_ src
|     |_person.ts
|_ tsconfig.json
|
Shared
|_ src
      |_utils.ts
|_ tsconfig.json
```

Here's **utils.ts**:

```
export function guid() {
  return "a guid";
}
```

Here's **Shared/tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,

    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Here's **ProjectA/tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,

    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "references": [{ "path": "../shared" }]
}
```

Here's the problem file - **person.ts**:

```
import { guid } from "../../Shared";

class Person {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  constructor() {
    this.id = guid();
  }
}
```

The TS compiler errors with **"Cannot find module '../../Shared'"**

[image]

What am I doing wrong when trying to import the **guid** function? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the full relative path to the file you are importing from, just as you would if the file were in the same project:

```
import { guid } from "../../Shared/src/utils";
```

Comment: I have used path mapping to make my module accessible in a better looking manner: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping. I know that this wasn't the original question but some people may like to use import * from 'my-module' instead of import * from '../../my-module' so I thought I'd mention that here.