# Sharing code between TypeScript projects (with React)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript3.0

This question: ["Cannot find module" error when using TypeScript 3 Project References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283465/cannot-find-module-error-when-using-typescript-3-project-references) was somewhat helpful.

So was this one: [Project references in TypeScript 3 with separate `outDir`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716934/project-references-in-typescript-3-with-separate-outdir)

But I am still having trouble getting this working efficiently with VSCode and React.

Project structure:

- client/src
- common
- server/src

common tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "composite": true,
    "outDir": "build"
  },
  "references": []
}
```

client tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../common"
    }
  ]
}
```

server tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../common"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using create-react-app in `client`. This has caused compilation issues. I believe I have solved this with `create-app-rewired` and `customize-cra` using this for `config-overrides.js`

```
const { override, removeModuleScopePlugin, getBabelLoader } = require("customize-cra");
const path = require("path");

const addCommon = (config) => {
  const loader = getBabelLoader(config, false);
  const commonPath = path.normalize(path.join(process.cwd(), "../common")).replace(/\\/g, "\\");
  loader.include = [loader.include, commonPath];
  return config;
};
module.exports = override(
  addCommon,
  removeModuleScopePlugin(),
);
```

In common, I have created a file `index.ts` which exports code from every file.

```
export * from "./messages/toServer/AuthMessage";
```

for example.

On the front-end and back-end, I can import code (to use) with a handwritten import statement:

```
import { AuthMessage } from "../../../common/build/messages/toServer/AuthMessage";
```

VSCode doesn't give any suggestions, but it accepts the import statement assuming the code is built.

I run `tsc -b -w` in common. This seems to work with manual imports.

It is possible to have:

- IntelliSense / auto-import When writing types such as `AuthMessage`
- Usable code that is imported. I have seen examples where types are supported, but code is not generated from common. Untested, but I imagine this works well for interfaces in a common directory
- Usability with React. Some relevant jabber: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6799. ts-loader supports project references, but I am unsure the status of babel-loader, which to the best of my knowledge, is the loader used by CRA. I got a partial solution with the code I provided above.

Guidance here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#guidance is very confusing. Any help with an explanation here is appreciated.

Other solutions?

- I don't want to publish and update a private NPM module.
- Using a program such as dsynchronize: http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/ might be easier where code is duplicated across two projects, but included in the `src` of both projects. It's not clean, and I can see some disasters with refactoring and an IDE attempting to re-negotiate import paths if the program is running...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible to have auto-import, VSCode's auto-import is terrible compared to webstorms which is god tier. I Would suggest swapping to Webstorm and i can almost gaurentee the auto import will pick it up.
Is the code your sharing just types or is it values aswell?

Comment: how do you deal with the non-react output location? it is not added to react index.html

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be working. The steps I took...

Create a base tsconfig in the project directory. (This is documented)

```
{
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./common"
    }
  ],
  "files": []
}
```

Add `"extends": "../tsconfig"` to both sub project tsconfigs.

export everything from all the files in `common/src`. (using `/common/index.ts`)
Update import paths to the common directory `import { ClassName } from "../../common"` (not individual build folders)

Run `tsc -b` in non-react projects for compilation. After very simple initial testing, it looks like my rewired react config just picks up changes to `common`. The `config-overrides.js` is a necessity.

This does appear to work in VSCode, however, after testing, I agree auto-import is superior in WebStorm.

When creating new files in `common`, they must be exported in `/common/index.ts` WebStorm auto import will give you a clue, VSCode is a little less obvious.